# Remove keyboard html textBox

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

Im trying to simulate a interface from a touchscreen phone, one function of the app is to allow to search but i want the user only to be able to click on the buttons on the virtual keyboard i'll be displaying and not be able to use the pc keyboard.
How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the input readonly (*to disallow keyboard input*) by using the [readonly attribute <sup>docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/input#Attributes)..

```
<input id="someid" value="initial" readonly type="text" />
```

you can still alter the value of it with javascript.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/XBxj6/